# Linear operators and their geometric meaning

Tags: linear-algebra

Linear operators $P, Q, R$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ have the following standard matrices:
$$\frac{1}{5}\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 3 \\
-3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}, \quad \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}, \quad \frac{1}{13}\begin{bmatrix}
9 & 6 \\
6 & 4
\end{bmatrix},
$$ respectively. Explain the actions of these linear operators
in geometric terms. Do we explain these with respect to reflection, rotation etc.? Maybe use the standard vectors $e_1$ and $e_2$ and multiply? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you need to describe these operators in terms of geometric transformations. They are all of the linear type, but there are specializations.

Comment: Can you recognize the pattern of elements in the first two matrices as one of the basic types of geometric transformation that you’ve learned? The last one is obviously a rank-1 matrix: compare its null space to its column space.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do it to calculate the determinant. It is an easy calculation for $2\times 2$ matrices, and it tells you what happens to areas of shapes under the transformation. Of particular interest are the values $1$, $0$ and $-1$. Linear operators with determinant $1$ preserve areas. Those with determinant $-1$ flip them around, but otherwise still preserve them. And those with determinant $0$ destroy all areas, that is, map the complete plane to a line (or even to the origin, but that's only true for the zero operator).

The next step is to determine the eigenvalues. Since you already have the determinant, the simplest way to get them is to also calculate the trace, and then use the fact that the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, while the trace is the sum.

If there are two different real eigenvalues, just determine the corresponding eigenvectors. Looking at what the transformation does to them should let you see what the transformation does.

If there's only one real eigenvalue, and your matrix isn't diagonal, then you'll find there's exactly one eigenvector. To see what the transformation does, look what it does to that eigenvector, and to a vector orthogonal to it.

It there's no real eigenvalue, looking at what it does to the standard basis is probably a good way to understand the action.

Comment: Great. So the final one is a projection into the real line (as the determinant are zero).

Comment: @squenshl: The determinant being zero is not sufficient to see that it is a projection, as it still could map that line non-trivially to itself. However that matrix also has trace one, which therefore is the other eigenvalue. The corresponding eigenvector tells you the line to which it projects. The other eigenvector tells you in which direction it projects.

Comment: Thinking again, the matrix is symmetric, therefore the projection must be orthogonal. This can also be checked by squaring the matrix and observing that you get the same matrix back.